# adding a custom back button now causes crash when going to RootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using a standard navigation controller in my app, but I recently had to make a change that needs to occur only when the user presses the back button on the navigation bar.  So in order to catch this, i am trying to create a custom back button as to catch its selector.

Now obviously the nav bar already has a back button, so im basically just trying to overwrite/replace it.  I'm not doing anything special, just allocating it and setting it to the navigation item.

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem: backBarButtonItem];
```

The problem however is after pressing back a few times (this screen is a few deep in the navigation), when i am backing to the rootViewController, i get an exception.  I'm guessing its because im adding a back button when there already exists a back button and somehow the navigation is getting out of wack, but I don't know what to change.

Comment: what does the exception say?

Comment: What kind of exception are you getting?  We'd need to see what gets stoked if you set an all exceptions breakpoint and enabled zombies too, then show us what the error is, and if it's a deallocated object that's getting a message.  Pushing a back button in place of a system one is nothing others haven't done so I doubt it would be that.  Look forward to seeing what happens.

Comment: Its just an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: What is the `backButtonClicked` method? Also, what is being clicked? A mouse? No, then why called it clicked? Why not just called it `goBack` or `goToRootViewController`. Make the names descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the `UINavigationController`'s back button is not a very good idea in general I guess, causing  undesired behaviour...

If you need to perform some actions before the view goes off screen again, you can just implement your required functionality in `viewWillDisappear`.

If you absolutely want to replace the back button, you should take a different approach:

Write a *category* on `UIViewController`, something like:

**UIViewController+BackButton.h**

```
@interface UIViewController (BackButton)
   - (void)setBackButton;
   - (void)didPressBackButton;
@end
```

**UIViewController+BackButton.m**

```
@implementation UIViewController (CustomBackButton)

   - (void)setBackButton
   {
      UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goBack)];
      [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backBarButtonItem];
   }

   - (void)goBack
   {
       [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
       if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(didPressBackButton)])
       {
          [self didPressBackButton];
       }
   }

@end
```

That way, you easily set up your custom back button in your view controller in `viewDidLoad` and implement the method `didPressBackButton` to perform your custom operation.

```
#import UIViewController+BackButton.h

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self setBackButton];
}

- (void)didPressBackButton
{
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: I can't add my changes into viewDidDisappear because the view is in a tab bar, and those fire when switching tabs, causing my changes to trigger when i dont want them to.  I only want them to fire when the user is backwards navigating.  

Ive also noticed this issue isn't really related to my back button, but rather manually calling popViewController. I have a cancel button on screen as well and this issue occurs then too.